# Going down fails when $R$ is not integrally closed.

Tags: commutative-algebra

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150295/a-counterexample-to-the-going-down-theorem) there is a counterexample to the going down theorem.

> I am pretty sure that the reason why it fails is because $R$ is not integrally closed in $A$, but I don't have any nice argument to show that this is true.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that $R = \lbrace f \in K[X,Y] \colon f(0, 0) = f (1, 1) \rbrace$ is not integrally closed, then notice that $X$ is integral over $R$, and $X\notin R$.

Comment: An equation of integral dependeance would be $T^2-(x+y-y^2)T-(xy^2-xy)$ right? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @math635 It seems that $f(x,y)=x+y-y^2\notin R$: $f(0,0)=0$ and $f(1,1)=1$.

Comment: @math635 A simple one: $T^2-T-X(X-1)$.