# Integral homomorphism induces a closed map on spectra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be an integral homomorphism (e.g. $B/f(A)$ is a integral extension). Consider $f^{*}: \operatorname{Spec}B \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$ given by $f^{*}(Q)=f^{-1}(Q)$. Show that $f^{*}$ is a closed map.

My problem here is that a I don't know how to describe the closed sets in the Zariski topology, since I have to show that given $Q$ closed in $\operatorname{Spec}B$ then $f^{*}(Q)$ is closed in $\operatorname{Spec}A$.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: As far as I know the closed sets in Zariski topology are of the form $V(I)$, the set of prime ideals containing a given ideal $I$.

Comment: Why do you want to prove this without knowing the definition of the topological spaces involved?! The claim follows from Going-Up, see also the almost identical question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383080

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283839/closedness-and-going-up-property-an-explicit-proof