# Application closed in Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the integral homomorphism $f: A \rightarrow  B$.
How do I prove that the map $f^*:Spec(B) \rightarrow Spec(A)$ given by $f^*(Q) = f^{-1}(Q)$ is a closed application.
Note:
1) I believe we need to show that $f^*(V(I)) = V(f^{-1}(I))$. I have already shown that $f^*(V(I))$ is contained in $V(f^{-1}(I))$ but I can not show the other inclusion.
2) $f^{-1}$ is the inverse image of $f$.
3) $I$ is any ideal of the ring $B$.

Comment: Is it supposed to be $f^*$ or $f_*$?

Comment: Presumably $f^*$ since it's contravariant.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387544/

Answer (score 3):

The massive hint that you need to solve your problem is the following result

> > **Theorem 5.10 Atiyah - Macdonald:** 
> >     Let $f : A \to B$ be an integral morphism. For every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ there is a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q} \subseteq B$ such that $A \cap \mathfrak{q} = \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: @Cesar: You accidentally created a duplicate account; with fewer than 50 reputation points, [an account can only comment on its own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). Follow [the instructions here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to merge your accounts.